# Click random button from random page

Tags: java, webdriver

My scenario is: I am working on price comparison web application and on each result page there are 3 apply now buttons. There are 4 result pages and each page have 3 apply now button. So there are 12 apply now button.  During my testing I would like to select one button for each test cases. To select apply now randomly on first page I got:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
List<WebElement> getApplyButton = driver.findElements(By.className("join-now"));
getApplyButton.get(rnd.nextInt(getApplyButton.size())).click();'
```

I am using java +web driver

Comment: rnd.nextInt() will return a value 0 - 1 (exclusive of 1), and from your method it will return 0 - the value of the size of getApplyButton. So if the size returns 1000, you're eventually doing `getApplyButton.get(0-999).click();

Comment: I tried "getApplyButton.get(rnd.nextInt(0-12)).click();" get below error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n must be positive
 at java.util.Random.nextInt(Unknown Source)

Comment: it's `getApplyButton.get(rnd.nextInt(12)).click();` if you want to get 0 - 11, if it's 1 - 12 then do `getApplyButton.get(rnd.nextInt(12) + 1).click();`

Answer (score 0):

```
int randomInt = (int)(Math.random() * 12);
```

`Math.random()` will give you a random double between 0 and 1 (exclusive of 1)

`* 12` will make that double be between 0 and 12 (although never quite 12, so you don't need to worry about IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Casting to an `(int)` will then truncate the decimal part leaving only the integer between 0 and 12.

*So, in your example:*

```
int randomInt = (int)(Math.random() * 12);
List<WebElement> getApplyButton = driver.findElements(By.className("join-now"));
getApplyButton.get( randomInt ).click();
```